# Javascript - Configuração de url's de acordo com ambiente

Tags: javascript, deploy

Minha aplicação tem um repositório de login, bem simples com javascript puro, no máximo um jquery.

Como faço para fazer uma chamada ajax passando a url correta de acordo com o ambiente que estou? Se estou no ambiente de desenvolvimento, quero usar localhost. Se estou no ambiente de homologação, quero usar o Heroku.

Pensei em usar o dotenv para manipular isto, mas como estou usando javascript puro, não tenho como dar um require("dotenv").

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Usa o location.

```
    var getUrl = window.location.host + '/api/login';
```

Comment: Analisei melhor a sua resposta e na verdade isso funcionaria, se a api rodasse na mesma porta do web. 

No meu caso, a api roda em uma porta, o webapp roda em uma outra porta e o login roda em outra porta. São repositórios diferentes no github e rodam separadamente.

Comment: Entendi e se você tentar assim ter uma url por serviço:
var getUrlLogin = window.location.host  + ':8000' + '/api/login';

Comment: Seria uma opção também. Analisei e resolvi solucionar esse problema com nodejs mesmo. No meu index.js, dei um require("dotenv") e deixei que as configurações do arquivo .env resolvam de acordo com o ambiente. Obrigado pela ajuda!